# Change the color of the CheckBox via Styled-Components

Tags: css, react-native, styled-components

I need to change the color of a CheckBox when it is selected. I'm using it as follows:

`index.js`

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
...
<CheckBoxes>
   <Label>Usuário</Label>
   <CheckBox
       disabled={false}
       value={myValue}
       onValueChange={setMyValue}
   />
</CheckBoxes>
```

`styles.js`

```
export const CheckBoxes = styled.View`
  flex: 0.25;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  text-decoration-line: none;

  > input:checked {
      color: #999;
  }
`;
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: did you try manage the attr `checkedColor` and `uncheckedColor` of @react-native-community/checkbox  ? i am not sure if it is possible with styled components.
Or try something like `export const CheckBoxes = styled.CheckBox`  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with `onFillColor`, `onTintColor` or `onCheckColor` ?

```
import CheckBox from '@react-native-community/checkbox';
...
<CheckBoxes>
  <Label>Usuário</Label>
    <CheckBox
      disabled={false}
      value={myValue}
      onValueChange={setMyValue}
      onFillColor={yourcolor}
      
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it setting the `tintColors` property inside the CheckBox

```
<CheckBox
   disabled={false}
   value={isDoctor}
   onValueChange={setIsDoctor}
   tintColors={{ true: '#FC8F00' }}
/>
```